# ¿Como sacar por pantalla el valor de una variable?

Tags: javascript, botón, random

Tengo el siguiente codigo en JS. Que es basicamente un boton que cada vez que lo pulsas cambia el fondo a un color aleatorio:

```
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');


function random(){
    document.getElementById('contenedor').style.backgroundColor = obtenerColorRandom();
   
}

function obtenerColorRandom(){
    let color= '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    console.log(color);
    return color;
}
```

Me gustaría que en vez de sacar la variable de color por consola, sacarla por pantalla para que pueda ver en cada ocasiones cual es el código de color del fondo.

Comment: Prueba con un alert(). Un saludo

Comment: Alert, setearla como valor en un span/p/div/input..., añadirla directamente al body... hay muchas opciones, qué es exactamente lo que quieres? Elige una manera e inténtalo, hay muchísimos tutoriales en google de cosas básicas de este estilo :)

Comment: Mi intención es en la propia pantalla añadir un string rollo "Background Color:" y añadirle el codigo de color. La opción de alert no me convencia porque lo que estoy practicando ahora, que acabo de empezar (claramente jaja) es a toquetear el DOM. He intentado varias formas pero al no tener muchisimo conocimiento todavia sobre como manejarlo me faltan recursos, o mejor dicho, como aplicar estos de manera efectiva

Answer (score 2):

Para *mostrar en pantalla* el color, puedes agregar un elemento dónde *mostrarlo* en el HTML y asignarle el valor en la rutina que lo cambia.

En el ejemplo a continuación uso un `<span>`, con el id `color`, al que le voy cambiando el `innerHTML` cada vez que se cambia de color.

```js
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');
const spcolor = document.getElementById('color');
const contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor');

function cambiarColor(){
  let color=obtenerColorRandom();
  contenedor.style.backgroundColor = color;
  spcolor.innerHTML = color;
}

function obtenerColorRandom(){
  let color= '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  return color;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor"><span id="color">#ffffff</span></div>
<button id="boton" onclick="cambiarColor()">Cambiar color</button>
```

El ejemplo está en un *snippet*, por lo que puedes probarlo aquí mismo haciendo clic en el botón *Ejecutar*.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, considera crear las referencias a los elementos en el ámbito global, así no molestas más al DOM para obtener por id, no tiene sentido hacer eso una y otra vez.

Tampoco tiene sentido la función `random()`, puedes cambiar todo dentro de `obtenerColorRandom()` precisamente porque ya tienes declaradas las referencias a los elementos que hay que cambiar.

Para mostrarlo en pantalla, he declarado un `<span>` para mostrar el texto del color, además, vamos a cambiar el color de fondo de `div` contenedor.

```js
/*
  Crea las referencias a los elementos 
  en el ámbito global, así no molestas más al DOM para esto
*/
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');
const contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor');
const textRandom = document.getElementById('textRandom');

boton.addEventListener("click", obtenerColorRandom, false);


function obtenerColorRandom() {
  let color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  contenedor.style.backgroundColor = color;
  console.log(color);
  textRandom.textContent = color;
}
```

```html
<button id="boton">Cambiar color</button>
<div id="contenedor">
  <p>El color de fondo es: <span id="textRandom"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');


function random(){
    var C = obtenerColorRandom();
    document.getElementById('contenedor').style.backgroundColor = C;
    document.getElementById('contenedor').innerHTML = C;

}

function obtenerColorRandom(){
    let color= '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    //console.log(color);
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En base a lo que comentas, mi solución sería:
primero, capturar el evento clic para ejecutar el codigo.
segundo, se captura el codigo de color de la funcion colorRandom()
tercero, asignarlo como background al contenedor
cuarto, crear un div que contenga el mensaje
quinto, mostrar el div

```
    //Evento que captura el click al boton
document.getElementById('boton').addEventListener('click', () => {
      const color = colorRandom(); //capturamos el color random
//se asigna el color de fondo al contenedor
      document.getElementById('contenedor').style.backgroundColor = color;
      
//esto es un if reducido (condicion)?cuandoSI:cuandoNO al no existir un div para contener el texto no se hace nada, si existe lo eliminamos con .remove()
(document.getElementById('texto')==null)?'':document.getElementById('texto').remove();
///creamos el elemento div para contener el texto
      const div = document.createElement("div");
//le asignamos id al div creado
      div.setAttribute("id", "texto");
//asignamos el texto que contendrá el nuevo div creado
      var newContent = document.createTextNode('El color es: '+color);
//asignamos el texto dentro del nuevo div
      div.appendChild(newContent);
//mostramos el div creado antes del contenedor
      document.body.insertBefore(div, contenedor);
    });
    
//funcion que devuelve únicamente un color random
    function colorRandom(){
      return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    }
```